# Developing site with many sections in a page using drupal

Tags: drupal-6

I am familiar with drupal. I want to go 1 step ahead and develop some complex websites. I came across site http://www.dakshintimes.com/

I want various sections in page like that. How do i create various sections in page like that. Should i create regions/ blocks in page and place content in that or which is the best way to do this.

Comment: there is a minipanel in a panel module. I think this is what you are finding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to look at the [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module. It allows you to setup a page with multiple column and row regions like that. Then you could assign Views Panes to those panels.